# ApplyBindings Twice, Validation

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a grid that has several business objects in them. Lets call them Product. When you click on the item, I make a AJAX call and take the data and create a Knockout viewModel that  is bound to a modal "window" (using bootstrap). The user can change the product, for instance they may change the name to something else, they can hit cancel or save. When the user hits save/cancel they are taken back to the grid where then can then click another product and thus pop up the modal with a new product (another AJAX call to the get the data, etc).

Well I was calling the KO.applyBindings(viewModel) again. I guess that might be a bad idea. What I am noticing is if the user does not type in the name (it is required), I get two validation messages that say "Name is required". So this tells me that two events must be bound (or something or other). so I did several google searches and I found several articles using ko.cleanNode(node), if you are going to call applyBindings twice. That did not solve my issue. I am using  knockout.validation.js and I also extend my name property like this:

```
vm.Name.extend({
        required: { message: 'Name is required.' },
        minLength: 1
    });
```

Is there anyway to clear out the extend or unApplyBindings? Or I am just using KO wrong? I really like it, but it takes some time to make it do what you want it to do (that is why they pay me). If need be I can perhaps make  Fiddle to demonstrate this..

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I will try to figure out how to get code to look like that.

Comment: I found a hack to fix this. I don't like it, but I needed to move on. For the time being, when I go back to edit another object, I don't applyBindings again, and I just set the properties of the viewModel with the JSON object I get from the server.. I set a flag  to indicate to me that I had already bind once, so the next time I just I skip the binding and do viewModel.name(data.name).. Not pretty but it works.. I don't consider this answered, I will be checking back to see if there is a better way to do this..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue but I was having the same problem.  I started with a sample on the github site that defined a custom template for displaying validation errors.  When I took it out, nothing changed and my exception went away.

I removed:

```
<script id="customMessageTemplate" type="text/html"><!--
    --><em class="customMessage" data-bind="validationMessage: field"></em>
</script>
---
<div class="row" data-bind="validationOptions: { messageTemplate: 'customMessageTemplate' }">
```

Hope this helps someone else.